# Link PHP with JQuery after clicking a button

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to process some PHP after a button is clicked with Jquery's AJAX function. The problem is that I can't link the JQuery's AJAX function with my PHP. There is no data to be send, I just want to procces some PHP code after clicking it. I tried adding a dummy data field in the AJAX code called 'btnpressed', but it didn't work.

I tried to find a solution, but, most sites just stick with form/data processing.

PS: note that the PHP code is on the same page as the HTML and Javascript.

**HTML:**

```
<button id='btn'>Do something</button>
```

**Javascript/JQuery:**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "samepage.php"}
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
if(isset($_POST['btnpressed'])){
//Do some database stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "samepage.php",
        data: { btnpressed: 'test' },
        success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
        }
     });
   });
});
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['btnpressed'])) {
   echo 'too localized';
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar without the console part. When I look into the console after pressing the button I get the HTML of another page (my homepage to be exactly). So the problem probably is related to sending the data to the wrong page?

Comment: @Jenthe Yes, the `url` property is not set correctly.

Comment: Ok, thanks to you I found the solution. Presumably, JQuery had some problems with my localhost configuration. I solved the problem by using url: ''. Edit: it's even enough to just drop the url part, it will use the same page as default.